# Sonar in TFS build

Tags: code-analysis, sonarqube

I want to integrate the sonar-runner with TFS 2010 build for analysis everytime the build is triggered.

How to acheive this and Is it possible to run the analysis in parallel with build?

Answer (score 1):

We use Jenkins CI with success to do this.

- First install [TFS client](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/8/7/987D6B7C-F577-4297-8F60-E4B6A9EA4BF9/TEE-CLC-10.0.0.zip).
- Install [TFS plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin) on Jenkins.
- Configure TFS client on Jenkins settings. Example: `C:\Microsoft\TEE-CLC-10.0.0\tf.cmd`

Work nice with parallel analysis.